# Developing With Multiple Computers

Tags: file, xampp, synchronization

I've been developing using XAMPP on a Windows 7 PC which has been going well.

A few days ago I bought a Windows 7 laptop to do work on the go.
So far I have been manually copying the newest edited files from the PC to the Laptop to develop while I'm not home, and copying them back again to develop on the PC when I'm home.

Of course, if I'm in a hurry, it is not the quickest way have the most recent files on my laptop.

Is there any way to sync the 2 XAMPP folders between the 2 computers once I'm home and on my local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synkron is great and suits my needs perfectly.

I have it set up to sync between my PC, Laptop and to backup to my usb memory stick on an interval (I det it to sync every 15 minutes).

http://synkron.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to get a Dropbox account (https://www.dropbox.com).

Install the dropbox desktop app on both computers and specify the Dropbox folder location where XAMPP lives (move it out of the way first and then copy it back on the most current computer).

XAMPP configuration files specific to the local computer may need to be separated in some way.

Comment: Im looking for it to run on a local network, i dont want my files in the cloud, also local would transfer files much much quicker and safer. I have found file syncing software, but most are usually just syncing files on the same system (such as pc and a usb drive). Im needing it to be pc to pc over a local network.

Comment: I'm not sure what your concern is about 'the cloud', but ok. Have you looked at rsync? Google rsync for windows.